# How can I combine any list? - JAVA

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

I have three classes. **Hero** and **Monster** classes extend **Character** class. And **Character** class extends **Object** class.

I have 2 ArrayLists, one for heroes, and the other one for Monsters. How can I combine them in one arrayList in one method.

```
ArrayList<Hero> heroes = new ArrayList<Hero>();
ArrayList<Monster> monsters = new ArrayList<Monster>();

ArrayList<Character> allCharacters = sumArrays(heroes, monsters);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/**
 * doesn't touch the given lists, creates one new list with all the elements inside the given lists.
 * @param lists lists to add together
 * @param <T> A common class between lists
 */
public static <T> ArrayList<T> sumArrays (ArrayList<? extends T>... lists) {
    ArrayList<T> summed = new ArrayList<T>();
    for (ArrayList<? extends T> list: lists)
        summed.addAll(list);
    return summed;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With Java 8:

```
public static <T> List<T> sumArrays(List<? extends T>... lists) {
     return Arrays.stream(lists).flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Note also the abstract type `List`, which is preferred to the specific implementation `ArrayList` - see [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).